# Squid separate access.log by http_port

Tags: linux, squid, configuration

I've AP 2 interface they're ip 192.168.200.1, 192.168.201.1 HTTP access from each interface i'm redirect it to difference squid port

```
192.168.200.0/24 ==> 192.168.200.1:3129
192.168.201.0/24 ==> 192.168.200.1:3130
```

with these line in iptables.conf

```
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.1:3129
-A PREROUTING -i wlan1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.201.1:3130
```

and in squid3.conf

```
http_port 192.168.200.1:3129 intercept name=ap1
http_port 192.168.201.1:3130 intercept name=ap2

access_log daemon:/var/log/squid3/ap1/access.log squid
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid3/ap2/access.log squid
```

But now it's write both file with same data how to separate access data to each access.log file.

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Squid does not support internal splitting of events to different access_log files, unlike Apache where you can log per virtual host.

If the current acces_log does not contain the information you need you can change that with the [logformat](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/) directive.

And if the reason you wanted the different log files is to generate statistics it is trivial to run a pre-processing script  to filter the existing log  by client ip-address